# Is it wrong to view convolution as template matching?

Tags: conv-neural-network, linear-algebra, convolution, cosine-similarity

I am reading about the convolution operation but I can't see how it can be seen as [template matching](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Elsigal/425_2019W2/Lecture6b.pdf).

Suppose that we convolve the input $\mathbf{X}$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with the kernel $\mathbf{K}$ (stride equals 1):
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then the output is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
*
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{green}{3} & 1 \\
1 & \color{red}{3} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $*$ denotes the [convolution operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#/media/File:2D_Convolution_Animation.gif).

The problem I see is that the output obtained from the sum of element-wise multiplication between the kernel and the local patch:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{green}{1} & \color{green}{0} & \color{green}{0} & 0 \\
\color{green}{0} & \color{green}{1} & \color{green}{0} & 1 \\
\color{green}{0} & \color{green}{0} & \color{green}{1} & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is the same with output obtained from the sum of element-wise multiplication between the kernel and the local patch::
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} \\
0 & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{1} \\
0 & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{1} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

That is, $\sum_{ij} (\color{red}{\mathbf{X}} \odot \mathbf{K})_{ij} = \sum_{ij} (\color{green}{\mathbf{X}} \odot \mathbf{K})_{ij}$.

Does the above observation mean that we can't view convolution as template matching, since different patterns in the input result in the same output?

Comment: I cannot follow your terminology.  To what do you refer when you use "filter" and what do you mean by "multiplying"?  (Convolution?  Elementwise multiplication?  Matrix multiplication?)  It's certainly not the case that the convolution of your $4\times 4$ matrix by the "local patch" gives the same result!

Comment: @whuber Apologize if misunderstood. I made changes so it is more clear where my confusion lies.

Comment: I'm sorry, I really cannot make sense of this, because merely changing the color of a symbol in a formula has no meaning whatsoever.  But if you were to expand your concept of convolution to include a border (or even a circular convolution), so that the output is the same size as the input, then *deconvolving* the output with the input will yield the filter, showing the filter is uniquely determined by the set of all possible (input, output) pairs.

Comment: @whuber I am just saying that given a matrix $\mathbf{K}$ and two matrices $\mathbf{X_1}$ and $\mathbf{X}_2$, it can be the case that $\sum_{ij} (\mathbf{X}_1 \odot \mathbf{K})_{ij} = \sum_{ij} (\mathbf{X}_2 \odot \mathbf{K})_{ij}$, even though $\mathbf{X}_1 \neq \mathbf{X}_2$. The color is just used instead of a subscript to denote the submatrices of $\mathbf{X}$.

Comment: Your equation $\sum_{ij} (\color{red}{\mathbf{X}} \odot \mathbf{K})_{ij} = \sum_{ij} (\color{green}{\mathbf{X}} \odot \mathbf{K})_{ij}$ does not make sense without colors. Maybe you could indeed disinguish $\mathbf{X}_i, \ i=1,2$ and invest one line more to explain that they are submatrices. I think this would prevent confusion :)

Comment: In your third displayed equation, should the symbol "*" perhaps be replaced by another symbol? $\odot$
? This could be the reason for @whuber's first comment. The wording "filter" seems to be related the base R's use of the name filter for a function that convolves vectors.

Comment: @Ute Thanks for the comment. I would change the wording "filter" to "kernel". The symbol "*" is correct since it denotes the convolution operation.

Comment: Maybe just explain what it means - use of symbols varies a lot, and folks have their own terminology in mind when they read posts (so do I)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**,
convolution alone is not equivalent to template matching based on [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity). You still need to normalize.

The cross products does indeed assign the same value, 3, to the upper left and the lower right submatrix.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} \\
0 & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{1} \\
0 & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{1} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
*
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{green}{3} & 1 \\
1 & \color{red}{3} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This is because it only counts matches of 1s between the data matrix and the kernel matrix. To adjust for mismatches, this count needs to be normalized. This is achieved by dividing with the square root of the product of counts in both matrices, in much the same way as the covariance between two random variables is divided by the square root of the product of their variances.

The **normalized correlation** between lower right submatrix and kernel becomes

$$
\frac{
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{1} & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} \\
\color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{1} \\
\color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{1} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
*
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
}
{
\sqrt{
\left\lVert
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{1} & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} \\
\color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{1} \\
\color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{1} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\right\rVert
\cdot
\left\lVert
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\right\rVert
}}
=
\frac{\color{red}{3}} 
{\sqrt{\color{red}{6}\cdot 3}}
=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
$$and for the whole matrix, the result is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{green}{1} & \sqrt{3}/6 \\
1/3 & \color{red}{{\sqrt{2}}/2} \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But in CNNs, we don't apply any normalization. This is what motivated my question.

Comment: You seem not to mention CNNs, and that "we don't apply any normalization", or did you? If you need to distinguish between the green and the red matrix, and you only want to fold it with a kernel matrix, then indeed convolution cannot be seen as "template matching" in the sense of the attached slides :-)

Comment: OK, I see you put the CNN tag. I have edited my answer and hope it matches your intention. But in a way, did you then not answer your question yourself? Did you read somewhere that convolution = template matching?

Comment: It was stated on the slides (the link on the OP) for template matching: "We can think of convolution/correlation as comparing a template (the filter) 
with each local image patch". And  in page 11 mentions the normalization step (and why it is needed giving an example with a fully bright image). So strictly, if we don't normalize is not necessarily template matching.

Comment: Maybe you can see convolution as a kind of imperfect template matching. But there are almost always small inaccuracies or even errors on slides, even more than in books. It is very difficult for lecturers to see themselves when they write something on slides that confuses the audience.  When you read slides on the net, don't take them as curated source. It would have helped to understand your question, and why you were confused, if you included the context, but now we know - I agreed with you in the edit :-)